# Can a Class be self-referenced?

Tags: c++

**If a structure can be a self-referential. like

```
struct list
{
     struct list *next;
};
```

as there is no difference between class and struct, except the default access specifiers.
then is it possible to write a class...

```
class list
{
     class list *next;
};
```

or may be is there any different syntax to get a self-referential class.?
if yes then how?**

Comment: As you mentioned yourself, there's *absolutely no difference* between a class and struct in C++ except default access modifiers.

Comment: In C++ you can, at least in 99.9% of cases, avoid typing the 'struct' or 'class' before the variable name as in: "class list { list * next; };"

Comment: Yeah, having to put "struct list *next;" is only a C thing. In c++ you would always just do "list *next;".

Answer (score 13):

Yes, but you can only self-reference a pointer or a reference to the class (or struct)

The typical way is just:

```
class list { list* next; }
```

If you need two classes to mutually refer to each other, you just need to forward declare the classes, like so:

```
class list;
class node;

class list { node* first; }
class node { list* parentList; node* next; }
```

When you don't have the full declaration (just a forward declaration), you can only declare pointers or references.  This is because the compiler always knows the size of a pointer or reference, but doesn't know the size of the class or struct unless it has the full declaration.

Comment: +1 - nice - but that last sentence should end with 'class definition' (not declaration :)

Comment: +1 Faisal/Lou. "class X;" is a "full declaration" (of an incomplete type). C doesn't call "struct list { int d; };" a definition, but instead calls it a declaration of a complete type. C++ signifies that by calling it a definition. Nice answer otherwise, of course.