# C++, instance of class within same class, parent/child structure within class

Tags: c++, static, parent, instantiation, iteration

I'm quite new to C++ and looking for some advice on the following problem. I'm trying to create a program that generates tree shapes (yes, real trees). These shapes are built completely from branches. For this, I started writing a class called Branch. The idea was that in main.cpp I create an instance of class Branch, which itself will create instances of Branch. This goes on for `NUMBER_OF_LEVELS` iterations.

For now, the program is structured as follows:

main.cpp:

```
#include "branch.h"

int main()
{
    Branch tree;
    return 0;
}
```

Branch.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const double NUMBER_OF_LEVELS=4;

static int nodecounter=0;

struct Branch
{    
public:
    int level;
    int nodenumber;

    vector<Branch> children;
    Branch *parent;

    Branch(int lvl,Branch p);
    Branch();
    static vector<Branch> getAllBranches();
};
```

Branch.cpp:

```
#include "Branch.h"

static vector<Branch> allBranches;

Branch::Branch(int lvl,Branch p)
{
    level=lvl;
    parent=&p;

    nodenumber=nodecounter;
    nodecounter++;
    allBranches.push_back(*this);

    if (lvl>1)
    {
        children.push_back(Branch(level-1,*this));
    }
}

//root
Branch::Branch()
{
    level=NUMBER_OF_LEVELS;

    nodenumber=nodecounter;
    nodecounter++;
    allBranches.push_back(*this);

    children.push_back(Branch(level-1,*this));
}

vector<Branch> Branch::getAllBranches()
{
    return allBranches;
}
```

Now, this program works, but I want to keep track of all `Branch` objects by storing each one in a `vector`, `allBranches`. At the end of the program, `allBranches` is indeed of size `NUMBER_OF_LEVELS`, as it should be (as for simplicity each object has only 1 child). When I try to extract the child or parent from main.cpp, however, the program crashes giving as error: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc`

I was wondering if this is caused by wrong usage of the `static` keyword? What is the correct approach for creating parent/child structures in C++?

Comment: Learn about [C++ smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_smart_pointers)

Comment: You could take a look at how linked lists work, it's a typical use of the previous/next mechanism.

Comment: The static here means, effectively, that you will have 2 different variables: one for main.cpp and one for Branch.cpp. You should useg a global variable in Branch.cpp, and declare `extern int nodecounter;` in Branch.h.

Comment: Other comments/answers aside, your current "getAllBranches" function returns a copy of allBranches. You probably want to return a reference to it `vector<Branch>& Branch::getAllBranches()`, otherwise you're create a new vector and filling it with copies of all your existing Branch objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have a ton of problems, the first few I spotted:

- static variable in header file: very unlikely you want to infest each TU with a distinct copy
- parent pointer in a structure without any handling and the structure; stored in a vector: too risky to end up with dangling pointers. Pointers to stuff in a vector are invalidated when you add more items!
- a very strange ctor that takes the same type by value
- the parent pointer is set to the address of the temporary copy sent in as parameter: obviously you meant to pass in a pointer to some stable node

that's enough showstoppers

minor things:

- using directive in header file -- restrict those to .cpp files
- postincrement used without good reason

the list not meant to be comprehensive

Answer (score 0):

> The idea was that in main.cpp I create an instance of class Branch,
>   which itself will create instances of Branch.

Please see [Can a Class be self-referenced?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1021740/1497596).