# how to make instance of same class within class in c++ program

Tags: c++

I am trying to make program to find shortest path between two points in grid; so I created a class called `FinalPath` and I am trying to keep track of position of surrounding region that is one step in north, south, east and west.

To keep track of this i created instance of array of type `Final` class but when I try to run program it shows `error-"error:field 'Find' has incomplete type of "FindPath[4]" "`.

Code that i entered in the class is as follow

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int a=0,b=0,g=0;
class FinalPath
{
public:
    vector<vector<int> >inputMat;
    vector<vector<int> >saveMat[4];
    int dist;
    int goal[2];
    int next[4][2];
    FinalPath Find[4];
};
```

I wonder why the compiler is showing me error for creating instance of the class?
What is the correct approach for creatinginstance of same class?
[image of code and error console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ2i0.png)

Comment: How do you think the compiler is able to work out the size of this data structure?

Comment: Possible duplication of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021740/can-a-class-be-self-referenced

Comment: @GianPaolo thank you.after replacing FindPath with static FindPath it works

Comment: @MandarSadye I deleted my post (before your answer), since I think your scenario don't fit the use of a static variable: now your code compile, but I think having your Find Variable shared between every FinalPath instance it's not what you need.
Consider using a pointer or a std:vector<FinalPath> as member variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put an instance of a class into itself - that would result in *infinite recursion*, as each of those instances would have another instance in it, and so on.

Use a pointer to a class instead, like `FinalPath * Find;`